# I want to return a parent that equal to 0

Tags: yii

i have a table in Database consists of (id , sort, parent, title) where parent is integer .
i want to return the records that has parent equal 0 by Yii framework.
i thought about using **findAllByAttributes** but i don't understand a thing :).
i have this

```
<?php $model = Father::model()->findByPk(1);
$items[] = $model->getListed(); // note that the [] is important, otherwise CMenu will crash.

$this->widget('application.extensions.CDropDownMenu',array(
      'items'=>$items,
)); ?>
```

So any help ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the records in the following 3 ways :-

#### 1.

Using **findAll()**

```
$model=Father::model()->findAll('parent= :id',array(':id'=>0));
```

#### 2.

Using **Criteria**

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->select='*';
            $criteria->condition='parent=:id';
            $criteria->params=array(':id'=>0);
            $model=Father::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

#### 3.

Using **Query Builder**

```
            $model=  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('Father')
                    ->where('parent= :id',array(':id'=>0))
                    ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create dropdown menu use this:

```
$list = CHtml::listData(Father::model()->findByPk(1),'id','name');

echo $form->dropDownList($user, 'country_id', $list);
```